# Checkbox selection

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have 3 multiselect checkboxes,after selection of every checkbox i will get the alret ,my requirement is i would like to know all three checkboxes are checked.If all 3 checkboxes are checked i would like to right one more logic

```
  var cat = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="newId#"]');
    for (var i = 0; i <cat.length; i++){
         //if all cheboxes are checked


      }
```

Comment: Provide little bit more effort to finish your code and then post it as a question

Answer (score 1):

If your checkboxes all have the same `aura:id`, you can easily check if they're all checked using the following code:

```
    var allChecked = component.find("checkboxes")
     .reduce((acc,val) => acc && val.get("v.value"),true);
```

If you're using ordinary input elements, then you have to call Array.prototype.reduce instead:

```
var allChecked = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="newId#"]'),
  (acc,val) => acc && val.checked,
  true);
```

Array.prototype.reduce takes two parameters. The second parameter is the starting value. The first parameter is the callback function applied to each element in the array, where `acc` is the value from the previous execution (which is the second parameter for the first index), and `val` is the item currently be evaluated.

Basically, for each input element, we're checking to see if all previous values were checked, and if the current array element is also checked (&&). The output of this call, `allChecked`, will be true if all the boxes were checked, or false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this. You just need one extra variable.

```
var lstcount = 0;
var cat = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="newId#"]');
for (var i = 0; i <cat.length; i++){
    lstcount ++;
}
if(lstcount  == cat.length) {
    //all checkbox are checked. You can perform your action here
}
```

Comment: no..that method is calling every time..thats the problem...otherwise your approach is correct

Comment: @LightningBoy It doesn't matter. unless your list size is same you don't get the alert. One more thing I am expecting you are querying all checkbox in list.

Comment: itsnt working..consider i selected checkbox..this method will call everytime means it will not work